# Detect any user interaction

Tags: javascript, events, user-interaction

I have a web application and when the user is logged in, I would like to display a popup after some time if the user doesn't do anything to warn him that he will be logged out soon.

So I used intervals and I reset it each time the user interacts :

```
$(this).mousedown(function () {
    reset();
});

$(this).mousemove(function () {
    reset();
});

$(this).scroll(function () {
    reset();
});

$(this).mouseup(function () {
    reset();
});

$(this).click(function () {
    reset();
});

$(this).keypress(function () {
    reset();
});
```

But in some case, the timer is not reset and the popup shows up when the user is still using the application, for example when scrolling in a div.

Do I have to add my reset function to all possible events in my application or is there a simpler way to detect any interaction ?

Comment: What element are you attaching the event handlers to?

Comment: The default value of $(this), the window I guess ?

Comment: You don't know...? O_o Well, the first thing I'd try is attaching to `document`.

Answer (score 10):

To cover all machine types (PC, Tablet/phone (touch device), PC without mouse..)

on the body tag add a reset for these events:

- onMouseOver
- onscroll
- onkeydown

That should cover any activity, I believe

Comment: Once my mouse broke and I had to navigate the internet using only my keyboard.

Comment: Ok so you could add an onFocus() to the first focus-able element on the page too. Thinking about it, onmouseover is good for PCs but not tablets etc. Maybe a combinatio of onmouseover (body), onscroll (body), and onfocus (first element whcih can receive focus) ?

Comment: If I'm scrolling the page with the arrow keys just reading text, onfocus never gets fired.

Comment: Actually the body can receive focus too so that should cover it all. Or onkeydown on the body tag might be better.

Comment: Like this -
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mouseover', reset);
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keydown', reset);
window.addEventListener('scroll', reset);

Comment: [This doesn't cover propagation blocking events](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/gQZJNr).  Also, I believe there should be touch events in there as well.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the answer above but in my case I don't have JQuery.

I also listen for touchstart and click. In addition I use debounce to wait for all interaction to stop for one second.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
let ListenForInteraction = function () {
  let lastId = Date.now();
  let callbacks = {};
  this.onInteraction = (callback) => {
    lastId++;
    callbacks[++lastId] = callback;
    return
  };

  this.handleInteraction = _.debounce(() => {
    console.log('Interaction')
    for (let i in callbacks) {
      if (typeof callbacks[i] === 'function') {
        callbacks[i]();
      } else {
        delete callbacks[i];
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleInteraction);
  document.body.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleInteraction);
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleInteraction);
  document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleInteraction);
  document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', this.handleInteraction);
};

let listenForInteraction = new ListenForInteraction();
export default listenForInteraction;

//USAGE
listenForInteraction.onInteraction(() => {
  localStorage.last_interaction = Date.now();
})
```